# Error while building php extension on Ubuntu

Tags: php, php-extension

I installed php5-dev, get php source, placed hello_world extension in

```
<php_source>/ext/hello.
```

I run this commands in hello dir:

```
phpize
./configure --enable-hello
make
```

But I have error: php.h not found :(

I tried to run ./configure in php source path, placed files from Zend/, TSRM/, main/ dirs to /ext/hello dir, but after running make I have many-many compiling errors. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
./configure --with-php-config=/path/to/php/bin/php-config --enable-hello
```